# Not able to fetch output. Return code 206. Missing values.

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please help. 
I am using synchronous calls to a remote server using ajax. Error was same with asynchronous call.

```
function create_vswitch(endpoint,data){
        var response=send_recieve(endpoint,data);
        console.log(response.params.id);
        return response.params.id;
}
function configure_server_vswitch(endpoint,data){
        var response=send_recieve(endpoint,data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));


function send_recieve(endpoint,data){
        var url=http://10.77.94.243/830a341f-5249-4704-bd49-a732063a7dcb + endpoint
        console.log(url);
        var response="";
        $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "POST",
             dataType:"json",
             data: data,
             contentType:"application/json",
             success:function(){console.log("success")},
             error:function(){console.log("ERROR")},
             async:false
             }).then(function(response){
                   resp=response;
            });
            return resp

$("#create").click(function() {
    var COMPUTE_VSWITCH_UUID=create_vswitch("/qvbn-switch-agent/compute.vswitch",{"name":"compute_vswitch_test102"});
    console.log(COMPUTE_VSWITCH_UUID);
    //var compute_server_uuid=
    configure_server_vswitch("/qvbn-switch-agent/compute.server",{"configuration":{"tid":"compute.vswitch","id":COMPUTE_VSWITCH_UUID}});
    });
```

The console output which i am getting is :

```
http://10.77.94.243:8280/830a341f-5249-4704-bd49-a732063a7dcb/qvbn-switch-agent/compute.vswitch
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
Done
739d4940-b12d-4a6c-8ba6-fad7d30ce78f
739d4940-b12d-4a6c-8ba6-fad7d30ce78f
http://10.77.94.243:8280/830a341f-5249-4704-bd49-a732063a7dcb/qvbn-switch-agent/compute.server
Done
{"code":206,"cid":"qvbb","reason":"missing values for attributes configuration","params":null,"result":false,"error":true}
```

As you can see the last o/t, it's saying that "missing values for attributes configuration". I am not able to understand what is the problem with this code. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `data: data,` with `data: JSON.stringify(data),`.

Comment: Thank u very much. This worked. But how it worked in first case.

Comment: You are passing the data in the "contentType" as "application/json" but what you send over is a simple JS object, which is why it never passes through. I suppose in the first case, the data is being JSON.stringified somehow.

Comment: In the next step i am doing
var networking_vswitch_uuid=networking_vswitch("/" + COMPUTE_VSWITCH_UUID + "/networking.vswitch",{"name":"networking_vswitch_test104"});

POST http://10.77.94.243:8280/qvbn/830a341f-5249-4704-bd49-a732063a7dcb/0000fa63-e6e1-4a6e-94a5-2c79f6ea43a5/networking.vswitch 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try to confirm if you are able to navigate to this page from a browser, I wasn't able to go to it from a browser, maybe the 404 makes sense in this case.